# WHAT is the meaning of Leading Length?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was checking out the difference between char vs varchar2 from google. I came across a word **LEADING LENGTH** in this [link](https://www.oratable.com/char-varchar-difference/) . THERE it was written that

Suppose you store the string ‘ORATABLE’ in a CHAR(20) field and a VARCHAR2(20) field. The CHAR field will use 22 bytes (2 bytes for leading length). The VARCHAR2 field will use 10 bytes only (8 for the string, 2 bytes for leading length).

**Q1**:How does the char field will use 22 bytes if the string is of 8 characters if (1 byte = 1 char)?

**Q2** What is the LEADING LENGTH ? why it does occupy 2 bytes?

Comment: Use more reliable sources https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476

Comment: The discussion is about what's stored physically on disk. When Oracle created their product, they decided that the `length` of strings will be stored in the first two bytes (instead of being calculated on the fly whenever it is needed). You may ask **why** Oracle did that, but that's an entirely different question. In any case, to store a `char(20)` value, Oracle will use 22 bytes, not 20 - the first two bytes will store the length of the string (20). Why it needs **two** bytes you can see in Gordon's answer.

Comment: @mathguy  u said that length of strings will be stored in the first two bytes. What is the length of the string in my given example 'ORATABLE' **8** or length means that is given within the brackets i.e **CHAR(20)**?

Comment: @SaumyojitDas - CHAR(20) means that the input string will be padded with spaces to length 20. If instead that was VARCHAR2(20) or VARCHAR2(100) or VARCHAR2(4000), the length would be 8 in every case. You can see what is stored (including the length) by using the Oracle function `DUMP`. If you are not familiar with it, use Google to find the Oracle documentation for `DUMP` - it is a **very** helpful function to know about and to use in many different issues you will face in the future.

Comment: @mathguy In char(20) if the string is of 8 characters then the left 12 characters will be filled by spaces? if so , then the total size shall be of how many bytes ?1 char =1 byte

Comment: @SaumyojitDas 12 spaces, but to the right, not left.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  said that "leading length" are two bytes at the beginning that specify the length of the string. What is the **beginning** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CHAR()` datatype pads the string with characters.  So, for `'ORATABLE'`, it looks like:

```
'ORATABLE            '
 12345678901234567890
```

The "leading length" are two bytes at the beginning that specify the length of the string.  Two bytes are needed because one byte is not enough.  Two bytes allow lengths up to 65,535 units; one byte would only allow lengths up to 255.

The important point both `CHAR()` and `VARCHAR2()` use the same internal format, so there is little reason to sue `CHAR()`.  Personally, I would only use it for fixed-length codes, such as ISO country codes or US social security numbers.

Comment: I don't see any benefit in using `char` even for those cases. I have heard it argued that it is self-documenting (e.g. `char(3)` says *'this column is expected to be exactly 3 bytes'*, but as it doesn't enforce it other than by adding unwanted spaces - and you could enforce it better with a check constraint and document it better with a comment - I think even that is unhelpful.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  u said that  "leading length" are two bytes at the beginning that specify the length of the string. **What is the beginning** ? Considering 2 bytes taken for leading length , the given string "ORATABLE"  should occupy 10 bytes then ( oratable is a 8 character word so 8 + 2(leading length)= 10)? is my assesement correct?

Comment: @SaumyojitDas . . . I think Oracle uses two bytes regardless of the length, but the documentation is vague on this point.  Some other databases use one byte if possible and otherwise two or more bytes.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff u said that "leading length" are two bytes at the beginning that specify the length of the string. What is the **beginning** ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  "Two bytes allow lengths up to 65,535 units; one byte would only allow lengths up to 255."  I did not understand the calculation.

Comment: @SaumyojitDas . . . The limit on the length of strings is affected by other factors such as the page size.

Comment: I am asking what are the 2 bytes of leading length ?what is the leading length plzz explain it to me in simple words.

Comment: One byte is 8 bits.  The numbers 0 to 255 fit into 8 bits.  Two bytes is 16 bits.  The numbers 0 to 65,535 fit in 16 bits.  If you don't understand this, then learn what binary numbers are:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number.